# Что такое бодун?

Tags: этимология

Помните песенку "Привет с большого бодуна"?
"Быть с бодуна" - то есть, с похмелья. А вот интересно, что это вообще за слово? "Бодун" - стало быть, "похмелье". Со словом "похмелье" все понятно - человек был во хмелю, а теперь, так сказать, последствия. А откуда взялось слово "бодун"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря: бодать, бодаться, боднуть, бадывать кого, толкать, бить... 
Бодастый (бык), бык-бодун - охочий бодать, бодущий, бодучий, бодливый...
О малом ребёнке: "Да, мы тоже бодаемся. А еще просто головку наклоняем и смотрим хитро и раскачиваемся на четвереньках под музыку или сидя."

С бодуна (с четырёх ног) быть - время возвращения к нормальному облику прямоходящего гражданина

Answer (score 6):

С бодуна – с похмелья.
Однако не факт, что это именно бодун. Слово это чисто разговорное: то с бадуна, а то и с будуна.
Почему же похмелье так называют?
Вот несколько версий, и все весьма правдоподобны.

Версия первая – рогатая.
Смотрим в Словарь В.И.Даля: Бодун м. -нья ж. бодуша, бодяга об. скотина изваженная бодаться. Вот наш бычок-бодунчик и телушка-бодушка. Дать бодуна, бодка; ударить рогом или чем иным, тычком.
Действительно, с похмелья голова тяжёлая, книзу клонится. Пьяный – на рогах домой пришел.

Версия вторая – посудная.
Бадун – диалектное название бочки, кадушки. Наверное, бадун – самец бадьи. Или бодни. Была и такая посудина – бодня.
С похмелья лицо опухшее, выпито много, и снова пить хочется. Счёт идёт на бочки.

Версия третья – бдительная.
Будун – может быть, от будить? С будуна человек пробудился. Похмелье – проблема того, кто проснулся наутро после пьянки. Кстати, будить и бдеть – родственные слова.

Версия четвёртая – праздничная.
В Кировской области была такая древняя языческая традиция – праздновать Бодун день – день поминовения усопших. Почему он так назывался, теперь не выяснить, но последние люди, его отмечавшие, объясняли так: «ложились на могилу и плакали…, вот как будто землю бодали». Правда, исследователи не отмечают, сильно ли народ напивался на этот праздник.

Версия пятая – топонимическая.
В Омской области есть село Падун, а в нём единственное предприятие - спиртзавод.

бадун бадья бдеть бодать бодня бодун будить будун диалекты Падун этимология - происхождение русских слов

Answer (score 0):

Элементарно - Ватсон. Мне сразу не понравилось само слово - Бодун. Будун - мешки под глазами - это искаженное слово Бурдюк. Как только всплыло это слово,  события развивались стремительно,  без моего участия. Мне оставалось только наблюдать со стороны.  Ну,  а в песне ...Привет с большого бодуна:   "вашему столу,  от нашего, эта маленькая бутылочка, вах, дорогой".

Answer (score 0):

По-видимому, текст песенки - первое закреплённое на письме свидетельство. А уж когда (и если) его кодифицируют...

Answer (score -3):

Состояние человека «с бодуна» -  после пьянки – похмелье, когда разламывается голова, мучит жажда и т.п.  Ох-ти мне, за что же Боженька так наказывает?

**בוא דון / бо дун** = «  **приходит + суд** » -----►
 ох-ти, суд  Страшный мне настал! Так черти мучают пьяниц в аду.